# Looking for the name of a black and white graphic novel about space colonization from the 1980s? where the STL starship exploded

Tags: story-identification, comics, hard-sci-fi

It was a black and white graphic novel or one-off SF comic book whose backstory involved space colonization in a star system after the slower than light starship (involving, maybe robots and artificial wombs) met with some disaster before the humans were ready to leave the ship. Colonization was therefore unplanned and poorly organized.

I don't clearly remember the plot, unfortunately. What I remember most were the hard SF theme, the crystal clear line art, including that of a crawler's journey across a dry moon (to a small base on that moon?).

It was a thin volume, I think in US Letter format, with maybe cream card cover, stapled, not bound, I think. Maybe it was issue 1 of something that didn't continue.

I'm pretty sure I read it in the mid-1980s, so it may date to the very early 1980s.